# Is it possible to add method to existing (built in) ActionScript Flash class without extending it and making a new class?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Is it possible to add a method to existing (built in) ActionScript Flash class without extending it and making a new class?

For instance I want to create my own fadeOut method and add it to the MovieClip class so that all MovieClips would have that method, and use it like so: ball_mc.fadeOut()

I DO NOT WANT TO EXTEND THE CLASS LIKE THIS:

public class NewMovieClipClass extends MovieClip{ ... }

Answer (score 3):

you can use `prototype` in AS3:

```
MovieClip.prototype.foo=function():void{
    trace("this is a test");
};          
var movieClip:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
movieClip.foo();//this is a test
```

Comment: Have you tested this? MovieClip extends object, which is dynamic, and therefore can have other methods and properties attached to it without the compiler complaining. But have you tried this with Number?

Answer (score 2):

With the advent of Actionscript 3.0 Actionscript is no longer prototypical. This sort of practice is in fact considered poor object oriented design as users of the MovieClip class would suddenly have new methods or unpredictable methods and thus break the design contract. I think the simplest way to accomplish this would be to subclass Sprite or MovieClip adding the methods you require. Is there a reason why you can't do this?

Comment: +1 agree with your answer, but you it's always possible to play with prototypes

Comment: prototype is not related to the 'dynamic' class modifier : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html#prototype

Comment: yes but being able to compile without mc.foo() causing issues is.

Comment: I agree with the above respondents. You *can* do what you ask with prototype, and it's up to you to decide if you *should*.

Comment: @Rudi you can use prototype on any object without any issue

Comment: @OXMO456 I know. All I am saying is that after running the prototype code you need a dynamic object to be able to call a new method you have defined. Luckily MovieClip is dynamic so that is possible in this instance

Comment: @Rudi ok, i didn't understand clearly your comment, your're right !

Comment: but you can compile with instanceObj["prototypeFunc"]() ; )

Comment: You can also turn strict mode off. That should allow you to call the function without the class being dynamic. Not recommended, but if you want to play with prototype, you probably expect to lose the compiler extras strict mode provides.